# Beginner MySQL Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, zerofill

I'm trying to create a table in an already created database.
I've already switched into the database using `USE church_fpip`.
Here's my code for creating the new table but for some reason it seems ZEROFILL is creating a syntax error.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE sermons (
    ->   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   year INT(4) NOT NULL,
    ->   month INT(2) NOT NULL ZEROFILL,
    ->   day INT(2) NOT NULL ZEROFILL,
    ->   title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ->   preacher VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ->   length INT(3) NOT NULL,
    ->   visible TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ZEROFILL,
  day INT(2) NOT NULL ZEROFILL,
  title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  preach' at line 4
```

Comment: You do know it's rarely a good idea to split a date up like that, going to bite your arse on a regular basis that is,

Comment: `MONTH` is a MySQL function, and I expect `YEAR()` and `DAY()` is too. They will work if you backtick them, but as @Tony says, just use a temporal type instead. Otherwise you'll be cast into the fiery pits of hell!

Comment: This is my first attempt at MySQL and at this point I'm guessing the method to which I'll want to parse later. Is it better to put it into yyyy/mm/dd format and use time or date methods in PHP to parse that time format up? @TonyHopkinson

Comment: (Btw, if you are using `ZEROFILL` just to get zero padding, don't - it's non-standard SQL and if you want padding on a field, you should handle that in your presentation layer).

Comment: Yes, MySQL will accept dates in the form yyyy-mm-dd (I think it's dashes, not slashes). It doesn't store it in that form, but it will use that form for input and output - and you can parse such output using PHP functions.

Comment: There are date, time, datetime, timestamp types. Don't confuse them with string representations like "dd/mm/yyyy" . The whole point of the types is you can display the same date in many formats. Going the other way '08/06/2010' => ??? Depends doesn't it. could be 8th of june, or 6th of august. Job is hard enough as it is, without making it harder by allowing both ways to be ambiguous.

Comment: **Where is the actual question on this question?** Please make sure to *explicitly* outline your question; otherwise, your "question" is just a problem that cannot have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `ZEROFILL` needs to be before `NOT NULL` such as

```
 month INT(2) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
 day INT(2) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
```

However I would recommend the use of `DATETIME` for what you are trying to do, instead of three columns representing day/month/year.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use date field instead of seperate year, month and day. You can parse date as per your necessity. This way it would help to keep your database clean and normalized.